# handle lazy load list of data on nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo

Previously, I used to call all the data at once. Now that I have lots of data, I thought of using lazily load concept. But I could not implement it the way I want.

Current working scenario is, I will first fetch only 6 items and when user clicks on load more button then more 6 items will be fetched but the problem is instead of fetching just the 6 additional items it fetches 12 items.

Expected one is, initially, fetch 6 items only. Now when user clicks on load more button then fetch only 6 new items not 12 items because there is already previous 6 items.

Here is how I am doing. Pagination is handled through pagination params.

```
import React from 'react';
import Router, { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useLazyQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import get from 'lodash/get';

const PAGE_LIMIT = 6;

const App = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const params = new URLSearchParams(router.query);
  const [trek, setTrek] = React.useState(params.get('trekId') || null);
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = React.useState(
    params.get('startDate') || null,
  );
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = React.useState(params.get('endDate') || null);
  const [trekDestinations, setTrekDestinations] = React.useState([]);
  const [offset, setOffset] = React.useState(0);
  const [limit, setLimit] = React.useState(PAGE_LIMIT);
  const [loadTrekDestination, { data, loading, fetchMore }] = useLazyQuery(
    FETCH_TREK_DESTINATION,
  );

  function showTrekDestination() {
    loadTrekDestination({
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
      variables: {
        queryInput: {
          queryParams: {
            ...(region && {
              trekRegionId: [region],
            }),
            ...(trek && {
              _id: trek,
            }),
          },
          paginationParams: {
            limit: limit,
            offset: 0,
          },
        },
      },
    });
    const trekDestinations = get(data, 'getTrekkingDestinationList.data', []);
    // console.log('did mount', trekDestinations); []
    // if (trekDestinations?.dataList) {
    //   setTrekDestinations(trekDestinations);
    // }
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    showTrekDestination();
  }, []);

  const trekDestinations = get(data, 'getTrekkingDestinationList.data', []);

  const handleShowMoreItems = () => {
    if (trekDestinations.count > limit && trekDestinations.count !== limit) {
      setLimit(PAGE_LIMIT + limit);
    }
  };
  // searching and filtering with many parameters
  return (
    <>
      <List
        trekDestinations={trekDestinations && trekDestinations.dataList}
        handleSearch={_handleSearch}
        handleShowMoreItems={handleShowMoreItems}
        loading={loading}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I tried to store data in local state but i get only empty [] in initials render. As this will have large list of data and also searching and filtering is there so, I do not have idea on efficient way to lazily load those items. Can anyone help me at this, please?

The stacks I am using are:
reactjs
nextjs
graphql with react apollo

UPDATE

i found there is a way to do using apollo `fetchMore` function so i tried it

```
const onLoadMore = () => {
    fetchMore({
      variables: {
        queryInput: {
          queryParams: {
            ...(region && {
              trekRegionId: [region],
            }),
            ...(trek && {
              _id: trek,
            }),
          },
          paginationParams: {
            limit: limit,
            offset: trekDestinations.dataList.length,
          },
        },
      },
      updateQuery: (prev, { fetchMoreResult }) => {
        if (!fetchMoreResult) return prev;
        console.log('prev', prev);
        return {
          ...prev.getTrekkingDestinationList,
          data: {
            ...prev.getTrekkingDestinationList.data,
            dataList: [
              ...prev.getTrekkingDestinationList.dataList,
              ...fetchMoreResult.getTrekkingDestinationList.dataList,
            ],
          },
        };
      },
    });
  };

  const handleShowMoreItems = () => {
    onLoadMore();
  };
```

but got an error `Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.`

non-iterable instance issue was there because dataList is inside data object. I solved it such way

```
const newResult = {
          ...fetchMoreResult,
          getTrekkingDestinationList: {
            ...fetchMoreResult.getTrekkingDestinationList,
            data: {
              ...fetchMoreResult.getTrekkingDestinationList.data,
              dataList: [
                ...prev.getTrekkingDestinationList.data.dataList,
                ...fetchMoreResult.getTrekkingDestinationList.data.dataList,
              ],
            },
          },
        };
```

Comment: Hard to say without trying it, however, just to share a doubt that came up looking your code, could be possible that you need to work on `offset` like starting from 6 rather then 0 ? 
```javascript
          paginationParams: {
            limit: limit,
            offset: 6,
          },
```

Comment: @Pierfrancesco Initially, i used offset but on hitting load more button it fetched next 6 items and previous 6 items was lost. I have now updated my question where I have tried using apollo fetchMore function. I could not update the result properly. Can you look at the updated one, please?

Comment: I solved it. Thank you @Pierfrancesco for your suggestion and your help.